# How to updated multiple records with Laravel and Eloquent?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.7

I have a project written using PHP on the top of Laravel 5.7. I am using Eloquent ORM to interact with the database.

I need to be able to update lots of records after pulling them from the database.

Here is how I am trying to do it.

```
$records = Record::where('Key','Test')->get();

$values = collecT([
  ['Id' => 1, 'Col' => 100],
  ['Id' => 2, 'Col' => 200],
  ['Id' => 3, 'Col' => 500],
  ....
]);

foreach($records as $record) {
  $newValue = $values->where('Id', $record->id)->first();

  if(is_null($newValue)){
      continue;
  }

  $record->ColName = $newValue['Col'];
  $record->save();
}
```

The above code does not write the updated value to the database. However, if I do the following it gets updated

```
foreach($values as $value) {
    $record = Record::where('Key','Test')->where('id', $value['Id'])->first();

    if(is_null($record)){
       continue;
    }

    $record->ColName = $value['Col'];
    $record->save();
}
```

Although the above code works, I have to make 1 select + 1 update statement for every record in the `$values` array. If the size of `$values` array is 1000. That's going to generate up to 2000 queries which are insane!

How can I correctly update multiple records in the database without doing range-update.

Answer (score 1):

If all the rows you are trying to update would get the same value it is an easy problem. The problem becomes a bit more tricky because all your rows need to be updated with different values. [This comment](https://github.com/laravel/ideas/issues/575#issuecomment-300731748) on a github issue of laravel has a solution that will do it with a single query, allowing him in that case with a 13x performance boost for 1000 rows to be updated compared to updating them one by one:

```
public static function updateValues(array $values)
{
    $table = MyModel::getModel()->getTable();

    $cases = [];
    $ids = [];
    $params = [];

    foreach ($values as $id => $value) {
        $id = (int) $id;
        $cases[] = "WHEN {$id} then ?";
        $params[] = $value;
        $ids[] = $id;
    }

    $ids = implode(',', $ids);
    $cases = implode(' ', $cases);
    $params[] = Carbon::now();

    return \DB::update("UPDATE `{$table}` SET `value` = CASE `id` {$cases} END, `updated_at` = ? WHERE `id` in ({$ids})", $params);
}
```

You can also try https://github.com/mavinoo/laravelBatch which does something similar.